# Finding distance between multiple points along a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, general-transit-feed-specification, advanced-license-level, arcgis-10.4

I'm using Arcmap 10.4 full license, all extensions, including Network Analyst.

I have a GTFS (transport) dataset from which I am trying to calculate distances between each point (alighting bus stops) to every other point (end point bus stops) along a specific bus route (quite a few of them).

I am a bit of a newby with network analyst (only taught it to myself 2 days ago, so please excuse any silly questions).

I have tried various options including spatially joining the bus stops to the bus route, splitting the bus route by the bus stops (makes all sorts of additional segments, which I can't understand why, because I dissolved the route in the first place), and doing route analysis, closest neighbour and cost distance in network analyst.

I can't figure out how to do this on multiple routes, and when I calculate it on one route (by selecting the route, and using a selection layer, ditto for the points), it doesn't follow the bus route but appears to be a linear euclidean distance measure, which I don't want, I need the actual distance along the bus route.

I've added all the data in using the gtfs to network scripting, but suspect I have gone wrong somewhere.

Is there perhaps a way to batch or do this for the whole dataset, rather than individually by route and bus stop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update (from the original questioner)

I figured out how to do this in Network Analyst.

I set up the network dataset using the " A[dd GTFS to a Network Tool](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0fa52a75d9ba4abcad6b88bb6285fae1)" going through all the steps.

Note, this tool gave me a couple of issues. You need to ensure it is installed prior to running it (and I used the regedit on CC cleaner and closed Arc when after it crashed, which it did a couple of times), and follow the use instructions, which are very [comprehensive](http://www.transit.melindamorang.com/UsersGuides/AddGTFStoaNetworkDataset/AddGTFStoND_UsersGuide.html). Also, it does not work on projected coordinate systems (Win 10 home, ArcGis 10.4) I found it worked best when unzipped to the same directory as my project.

I then added a streets layer, and another transit layer (matched to street).

I selected the route I wanted by attribute, and saved it as a selection layer. I also did the same with the bus stops on the route (from an Excel spreadsheet of the data). I saved the stops as two selection layers (from and to).

I then ran a closest facility analysis, using the from and to stops, with the from stops as facilities, and the to stops as incidents, and travelled from facility to incident. Ensure that when setting up the parameters for this, that on the analysis settings, the numbers of facilities to find is set at the number you have inputted. Run analysis, and voila, you get routes, along a specified route, with distances between each point.

If you do this on OD Cost Analysis, it does not use a specified route (not in the way I did it)

Comment: you should mark this answer with the green tick mark at the upper left, to indicate that you have found an adequate answer for your question. This is how others can more easily find questions that need answering.